# Why am I getting the error [NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, subscript

In my `removeTextFieldObserver` function below, I’m getting an error "[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named ‘subscript’”.  If it’s a dictionary surely it should have a subscript?

```
func showSimpleAlert() 
{
    let title = NSLocalizedString("A Short Title is Best", comment: "")
    let message = NSLocalizedString("A message should be a short, complete sentence.", comment: "")
    let cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    // Create the action.
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .Cancel) { action in
        NSLog("The simple alert's cancel action occured.")
    }

    // Add the action.
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func removeTextFieldObserver()
{
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: alertController.textFields[0])
}
```

Comment: What is `textFields` ? How did you declare it ?

Comment: textFields[0], it is default property of alertController at index 0

Comment: Try. var arr = alertController.Textfield? as NSArray then arr[0]

Answer (score 0):

That’s because `[NSObject:AnyObject]?` is an optional.  It might contain an `[NSObject: AnyObject]` or it might not, and contain a `nil`.

To use the value, you need to “unwrap” it first:

```
if let object = alertController.textFields?[0] {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: object)
}
```

`alertController.textFields?[0]` says “if `alertController.textFields` is not `nil`, return the `[0]`th element, otherwise return `nil`.  Then the `if let object =` says “if the vale on the right is not `nil`, unwrap it and assign that value to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

`textFields` is an optional property, to access the subscript you have to unwrap it.

```
textFields?[0]
```

Should work. If the alert controller has no textFields, this will send nil.